# How to animate counting up numbers with comma in animejs?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I using [animejs](https://animejs.com/) to increase numbers with animation.

Right now the animation couning from zero to 8940000 - and animejs update the dom correctly.

But I want to repesent the number with comma. for example: 0 -> 0, 10 -> 10, 100 -> 100, 1000 -> 1,000, 8940000 -> 8,940,000.

I try to do: `innerText: [0, 8,940,000]` but I got an error: `Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.`.

Any ideas how to make it work?

[I made an example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iejgek)

Comment: Error occurred (6:3)
Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

You could use numeral in update method:

```
var yourElement = document.querySelector("#app");

anime({
  targets: yourElement,
  innerText: [0, 8940000],
  easing: "linear",
  round: true,
  update: function(a) {
    const value = a.animations[0].currentValue;
    const formattedNumber= numeral(value).format("0,000,000");
    yourElement.innerHTML = formattedNumber;
  }
});
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rntnte)